# How can I create info array or list of all the doors objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsReplace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class TransformInfo
    {
        public Vector3 pos;
        public Quaternion rot;
        public Vector3 scale;
    }

    public void GetDoors()
    {
        var DoorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Left");
        var DoorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Right");


        TransformInfo[] trnfrm = new TransformInfo[DoorsLeft.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < trnfrm.Length; i++)
        {
            trnfrm[i] = new TransformInfo();

            trnfrm[i].pos = DoorsLeft[i].transform.position;
            trnfrm[i].rot = DoorsLeft[i].transform.rotation;
            trnfrm[i].scale = DoorsLeft[i].transform.localScale;
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine for the DoorsLeft but I want that trnfrm will include also the info of the objects from DoorsRight so the array or list trnfrm structure will be something like that :

```
DoorLeft 0...info inside
DoorLeft 1...info inside
.
.
.
DoorRight 0...info inside
DoorRight 1...info inside
```

This is how the array looks like now :

[image: Doors array]

I want it to include also the DoorRight and to add some id like a string to know what door info is belong to for example :

```
DoorLeft 0...info inside
DoorLeft 1...info inside
.
.
.
DoorRight 0...info inside
DoorRight 1...info inside
```

And how to read the info back into GameObjects ?

The main goal is to Instantiate a prefab at the doors positions and same doors rotations and scaling.

So this is what I did :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsReplace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public struct TransformInfo
    {
        public string ID;
        public Transform Transform;

        public Vector3 pos;
        public Quaternion rot;
        public Vector3 scale;

        public TransformInfo(Transform transform, string id)
        {
            Transform = transform;
            ID = id;
            // For this kind of stuff I always prefer working on the local values
            pos = transform.localPosition;
            rot = transform.localRotation;
            scale = transform.localScale;
        }

        public void Apply()
        {
            Transform.localPosition = pos;
            Transform.localRotation = rot;
            Transform.localScale = scale;
        }

        public void Apply(Transform transform)
        {
            transform.localPosition = pos;
            transform.localRotation = rot;
            transform.localScale = scale;
        }
    }

    public GameObject prefabToInit;

    // Note your method should probably return something
    public TransformInfo[] GetDoors()
    {
        var DoorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Left");
        var DoorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Right");

        TransformInfo[] trnfrm = new TransformInfo[DoorsLeft.Length * 2];

        int trnfrmIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DoorsLeft.Length; i++)
        {
            trnfrm[trnfrmIndex] = new TransformInfo(DoorsLeft[i].transform, $"{i}_L");
            trnfrm[trnfrmIndex + 1] = new TransformInfo(DoorsRight[i].transform, $"{i}_R");

            trnfrmIndex += 2;
        }

        return trnfrm;
    }

    public void ApplyDoors()
    {
        foreach (var info in GetDoors())
        {
            info.Apply(Instantiate(prefabToInit.transform));
        }
    }
}
```

And calling this ApplyDoors from a editor script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectsReplace))]
public class ObjectsReplaceEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        ObjectsReplace myScript = (ObjectsReplace)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            myScript.ApplyDoors();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's Instantiating the prefab many times at the main hierarchy node and not as the doors as childs so it put all the prefabs at the same area instead where the doors are :

[image: Prefabs after Instantiated]

But now I see that it's changing the original source prefab asset to a cube :

[image: Prefab changed to cube scaled to 1,1,1]

But the original prefab source asset scaling was :

[image: Original prefab]

Not sure why it's changed the prefab it self scaling to 1,1,1

And this is a screenshot of my scene game and example on the right of how the doors should be placed and on the left far other places with doors that this prefab should be Instantiated at. I don't want to destroy the doors but to Instantiate the prefab on the doors at the doors positions with the right rotations like the doors are :

The doors in green at the right are doors left and right that I manually add the DoorShieldFXLocked Variant prefab. And this is how all the doots should look like after Instantiating the DoorShieldFXLocked prefab.

[image: Example door with the prefab on Door_Left and on Door_Right]

Each door is built with Door_Left and Door_Right and on each door it should be Instantiating the DoorShieldFXLocked but instead it's changing the DoorShieldFXLocked scale to 1,1,1 and put all the Instantiated DoorShieldFXLocked's at other area almost at the same place.

And this is a screenshot in the Hierarchy of example of how a door is built the structure of a door :

Each door is a child of a prefab. It's just the prefab I could not fit it in the screenshot but above all this there is a prefab. So I wonder if there is a way also the apply the prefab of each door ? But this is a door structure example :

[image: Door structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey before wasn't clear what you wanted so here the updated answer:

The problem was that

1. This would apply the exact same **local** rotation, position and scale to the DoorShieldFX objects .. this is not what you want since these positions and rotations would be relative to it's parents. So yeah in this case you rather wanted the global transforms.
2. You spawn all of them into the scene root, not as children of according doors.

What you rather want to do in this case is

```
public struct TransformInfo
{
    public Transform Transform;

    public Vector3 pos;
    public Quaternion rot;
    public Vector3 scale;

    public TransformInfo(Transform transform)
    {
        Transform = transform;
        
        pos = transform.position;
        rot = transform.rotation;
        scale = transform.scale;
    }

    public void Apply(Transform transform)
    {
        // First of all it is important that
        // this new FX is a child of the according door so
        transform.SetParent(Transform, false);

        // Then you can put it in position if it is still needed
        // since actually SetParent with worldPositionStays = false
        // should actually already do that anyway.
        transform.position = pos;
        transform.rotation = rot;
        // Not sure about the scale since it would be relative to the door
        // depends on your case
    }
}
```

Then in order to get the infos from both lists you could simply do e.g. (assuming the amount is equal for left and right)

```
// Note your method should probably return something
public TransformInfo[] GetDoors()
{
    var DoorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Left");
    var DoorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Right");

    TransformInfo[] trnfrm = new TransformInfo[DoorsLeft.Length * 2];

    trnfrmIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DoorsLeft.Length; i++)
    {
        trnfrm[trnfrmIndex] = new TransformInfo(DoorsLeft[i]);
        trnfrm[trnfrmIndex+1] = new TransformInfo(DoorsRight[i]);

        trnfrmIndex += 2;
    }

    return trnfrm;
}
```

---

Then for reapply these to all doors you can do

```
foreach(var info in transformInfos)
{
    info.Apply(Instantiate (prefabToInit).transform);
}
```

---

The ID is then actually not needed anymore.

---

## However

Well actually the entire script is not needed for your goal since you could also simply iterate over the two arrays like

```
public void ApplyDoors()
{
    var DoorsLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Left");
    var DoorsRight = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door_Right");

    foreach(var door in DoorsLeft)
    {
        Instantiate(prefabToInit, door.transform.position, door.transform.rotation, door.transform);
    }

    foreach(var door in DoorsRight)
    {
        Instantiate(prefabToInit, door.transform.position, door.transform.rotation, door.transform);
    }
}
```

without the need of any in-between class!

Comment: I edited my question with what I want to do and what I did so far and why it's not working. I forgot to mention what is the main goal. Sorry.

Comment: I updated the answer to a new version after knowing your goal now. The scale you want to apply depends on your needs. Also actually simply doing `SetParent(Transform, false)` should probably be enough so the objects already end up in the correct place and rotation